# How can I update strings within an SQL server table based on a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `A` and `B`. `A` has an Id and a string with some embedded information for some text and ids from a table `C` that is not shown

```
Aid| AString
 1   "<thing_5"><thing_6">"
 2   "<thing_5"><thing_6">"

 Bid|Cid|Aid
  1   5   1
  2   6   1
  3   5   2
  4   6   2
```

I realise this is an insane structure but that is life.

I need to update the strings within `A` so that instead of having the `Cid` they have the corresponding `Bid` (related by the `Aid` and `Bid` pairing)

Is this even something I should be thinking of doing in SQL... `A` has about 300 entries and `B` about 1200 so not something doing by hand

For clarity I wish for `B` to remain the same and `A` to finally look like this

```
Aid| AString
 1   "<thing_1"><thing_2">"
 2   "<thing_3"><thing_4">"
```

Comment: Can there be numbers in `AString` other than `cid`'s?

Comment: Do you have all the time two Cids for each row from table A?

Comment: @TT. well noticed. There can be :(

Comment: @CorinaGheorghe no there can be lots, and they are not always 5 and 6 :)

Comment: So how can they be distinguished from any other numbers? Are there any markers that delimit the `cid`'s? Or are the `cid`'s always embedded in `<..._CID>`?

Comment: @TT. They always have `thing_` before them, and in real life a `"` mark after. so the pattern is `thing_X"`

Comment: Updated my script, tried finding a better way but it's all cumbersome. Do you need to do this often? Are there performance requirement. If you don't have to do this often and performance isn't terribly important my script will do fine.

Comment: @TT. It is a one shot deal! performance is NOT important! Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script relies on generating dynamic SQL statements to update the table, then executes those statements.

- Taking into account that the `cid`'s are within `thing_` and `"`:
- First replaces the `cid`'s using a placeholder (`$$$$$$` in this case) to account for the fact that `cid`'s and `bid`'s may overlap (example, changing 3->2 and later 2->1)
- Then changes the placeholders to the proper `bid`

---

```
CREATE TABLE #a(aid INT,astr VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO #a(aid,astr)VALUES(1,'<thing_5"><thing_6">'),(2,'<thing_5"><thing_6">');

CREATE TABLE #rep(aid INT,bid INT,cid INT);
INSERT INTO #rep(bid,cid,aid)VALUES(5,6,1),(6,5,1),(3,5,2),(4,6,2);

DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX)=(
    SELECT
        'UPDATE #a '+
        'SET astr=REPLACE(astr,''thing_'+CAST(r.cid AS VARCHAR(16))+'"'',''thing_$$$$$$'+CAST(r.cid AS VARCHAR(16))+'"'') '+
        'WHERE aid='+CAST(a.aid AS VARCHAR(16))+';'
    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT aid FROM #a AS a) AS a
        INNER JOIN #rep AS r ON
            r.aid=a.aid
    FOR 
        XML PATH('')
);
EXEC sp_executesql @cmd;

SET @cmd=(
    SELECT
        'UPDATE #a '+
        'SET astr=REPLACE(astr,''thing_$$$$$$'+CAST(r.cid AS VARCHAR(16))+'"'',''thing_'+CAST(r.bid AS VARCHAR(16))+'"'') '+
        'WHERE aid='+CAST(a.aid AS VARCHAR(16))+';'
    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT aid FROM #a AS a) AS a
        INNER JOIN #rep AS r ON
            r.aid=a.aid
    FOR 
        XML PATH('')
);
EXEC sp_executesql @cmd;

SELECT * FROM #a;

DROP TABLE #rep;
DROP TABLE #a;
```

Result is:

```
+-----+----------------------+
| aid |         astr         |
+-----+----------------------+
|   1 | <thing_6"><thing_5"> |
|   2 | <thing_3"><thing_4"> |
+-----+----------------------+
```

Comment: Amazing answer thanks for your help... Now what is this 'backup' you talk about :D

Comment: @Loofer =) Hehehe something mysterious I've only read about. You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with SQL with something like below. It wasn't clear to me how c was related, but you can adjust it as necessary...

```
create table a (
Aid int null,
AString varchar(25) null)

insert into a values(1,'"<thing_5"><thing_6">"')
insert into a values(2,'"<thing_5"><thing_6">"')

create table b (
Aid int null,
Bid int null,
Cid int null)

insert into b values(1,1,5)
insert into b values(1,2,6)
insert into b values(2,3,5)
insert into b values(2,4,6)

UPDATE Ax
SET Ax.ASTRING = REPLACE(Ax.ASTRING, 'thing_' + cast(cID as varchar(1)),'thing_' + cast(BID as varchar(1)))
FROM A Ax
INNER JOIN Bx
on ax.Aid=bx.Aid
and Ax.AString like '%thing_' + cast(Cid as varchar(1)) + '%'
```

Comment: An UPDATE statement can change a row at most once. This will never work.

Comment: Thanks @TT. I was writing this from my phone. If you run it twice, it will run the first replace on the row, and then run it a second time would complete the second replace. I am updating my code a little as well.